# Sum of cash and cheque from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the sum of cash and cheque amount from a table in 2 columns order by salesman.

**My table is like this:**

```
Salesman A  Cash    21151
Salesman B  Cash    34510
Salesman C  Cash    21252
Salesman D  Cash    13356
Salesman A  Cheque  13944
Salesman B  Cheque  87368
Salesman C  Cheque  20182
Salesman D  Cheque  23862
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT Ca.Cash,  Cr.Credit FROM 
    (SELECT Salesman, PayMode, SUM(Collection) AS Cash
        FROM Prospect_Detail WHERE(Purpose = 'Collections') AND (PayMode = 'Cash')
        GROUP BY Salesman, PayMode) AS Ca 
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT Salesman, PayMode, SUM(Collection) AS Credit
        FROM Prospect_Detail WHERE(Purpose = 'Collections') AND (PayMode = 'cheque')
        GROUP BY Salesman, PayMode) Cr
```

And I need to get the result like this:

```
Salesman       Cash      Cheque
Salesman A     21151     13944
Salesman B     34510     87368
Salesman C     21252     20182
Salesman D     13356     23862
```

Comment: What is current SQL's output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot your table on the following way

```
With c as(
SELECT Salesman
     , Paymode
     , Sum(Collection) AS Cheque
FROM 
    Prospect_Detail
GROUP BY 
      Salesman
    , Paymode
)
Select Salesman
      ,[Cash]
      ,[Cheque] 
From C
Pivot(
    Sum(Cheque)
    For Paymode in ([Cash],[Cheque]) 
) as pvt;
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following.

```
create table #Temp (name varchar(50), collectionType varchar(10), amount int)
insert into #Temp values
('Salesman A', 'Cash', 21151),
('Salesman B', 'Cash', 34510),
('Salesman C', 'Cash', 21252),
('Salesman D', 'Cash', 13356),
('Salesman A', 'Cheque', 13944),
('Salesman B', 'Cheque', 87368),
('Salesman C', 'Cheque', 20182),
('Salesman D', 'Cheque', 23862)

SELECT name, Cash, cheque 
FROM  
(SELECT collectionType, name , amount 
    FROM #Temp) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(amount)  
FOR collectionType IN ( Cash ,  Cheque)  
) AS PivotTable;
```

The output is as shown below

```
name        Cash    cheque
--------------------------
Salesman A  21151   13944
Salesman B  34510   87368
Salesman C  21252   20182
Salesman D  13356   23862
```

You can find the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/BCPH42863).

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions to pivot are a VAST over-complication for this. Ignore them. Just use conditional summation. A simplified example:

```
select Salesman, sum(case Paymode when 'Cash' then Collection else 0 end) as Cash, ...
from Prospect_Detail 
where Purpose = 'Collections'
group by Salesman 
order by Salesman;
```

Comment: I don't see that `PIVOT` is any more or less complicated than this. Swings and roundabouts for me really

Comment: @MartinSmith You may not, but OP is asking a question that is fairly basic for anyone with significant experience. Therefore, pivot (which is a command that one usually masters later) is IMO vastly over-complicated **for OP**.  You have to walk before you can run.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `PIVOT` operator to get the desired result:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
   SalesMan varchar(50),
   PayType VARCHAR(10),
   Amount INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    SalesMan,
    PayType,
    Amount
)
VALUES
  ('Salesman A', 'Cash',  21151)
, ('Salesman B', 'Cash',    34510)
, ('Salesman C', 'Cash',    21252)
, ('Salesman D', 'Cash',    13356)
, ('Salesman A', 'Cheque',  13944)
, ('Salesman B', 'Cheque',  87368)
, ('Salesman C', 'Cheque',  20182)
, ('Salesman D', 'Cheque',  23862)

SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
)AS FooData
PIVOT(
    AVG(FooData.Amount)
    FOR PayType IN ([Cash], [Cheque])
) AS FooPivot
```

Ouptut:

```
SalesMan    Cash    Cheque
Salesman A  21151   13944
Salesman B  34510   87368
Salesman C  21252   20182
Salesman D  13356   23862
```